# Animate both mounting and unmounting of an Om component

Tags: animation, clojurescript

Is there a straightforward way to fade a component in when mounting, and fade a component out when unmounting?

I can get a component to fade in by using some jquery in the `did-mount` function, but getting it to fade out in the `will-unmount` function just doesn't work (the unmount happens instantly).

What is the standard way of animating the mounting and unmounting of Om components?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27127541/21037).

Basically, you can use [ReactCSSTransitionGroup](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) from `react-with-addons` to create CSS transitions for mounting and unmounting:

```
(def css-trans-group (aget js/React "addons" "CSSTransitionGroup"))

...

(apply
  css-trans-group
  #js {:transitionName "example"}
  (om/build-all my-component list-of-data))))
```