# revealing a hidden div using om (/react)

Tags: css, reactive-programming, clojurescript, om

Using Om, I've set up a component that I want to reveal when a user presses a button. The effect should be that the div *slides in from the right*. What is the best way to structure this in am Om project?

I can't do something hacky like:

```
(let [the-div (. js/document (.getElementById "the-div"))]
    (.setAttribute dashboard "width" "500px"))
```

Because I think om sets up the components in the shadow dom, and I get an error: `Cannot read property 'style' of null`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of achieving this effect? Program structure or any tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to specify the width in your component as a function of state, and change the state.

```
[:div {:style {:width (if big? "500px" "0px")}}]
```

Or only conditionally render it, or use a class etc.

When it comes to animation, making it *slide* in, things are a little tricky...
You can use a CSSTransitionGroup
[Creating animations with Clojurescript Om](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368485/creating-animations-with-clojurescript-om)

Personally I find CSSTransitionGroups too fiddly, and prefer a more direct declarative approach
http://timothypratley.github.io/reanimated/#!/timothypratley.reanimated.examples
The basis for reanimated is extremely simple and could be recreated for om... it updates state every render toward a target goal and then stops.