# CSS3 animation - arc between 2 elements

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I want to create an animation between 2 elements with dynamic width between them (depend on the screen size).

Somebody can give me an hint how to implement? See attached image.

[image: Animate between 2 elements with unknown distance]

Comment: Try google..you will get everything.

Comment: Trust me I tried - didn't get the answer for this specific question. If you have a good link you're welcome to share with me.

Comment: could you add that code that you have tried via jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: Hope this link will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761993/css3-translate-across-an-arc

Comment: [This](http://dabblet.com/gist/1615901) is a good start but couldn't think how to dynamically set the start and end point and also how to control the angle of the arc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you manage to get a div to extend the distance that you want to cover, this solution can work:

set 2 animations, one for horizontal axis, and another for the vertical axis

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  position: relative;
}

.container:nth-child(2) {
  width: 800px;
}

.inner {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation-name: arctop, arcleft;
  animation-duration: 2s, 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear, linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite, infinite;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes arctop {
  0% {top: 75px; animation-timing-function: ease-out;}
  50% {top: 0px; animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
  100% {top: 75px;}
}

@keyframes arcleft {
  0% {left: 0px;}
  100% {left: calc(100% - 25px)}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I never know I can use more than one animation on an element. Thanks a lot for your answer! @vals

Comment: Happy that it helped !   But browser support for multiple animations is not so great, so may be you will want to create an intermediate element, and asign one animation to each one.